# Logical AND operation without using double ampersands

Tags: javascript, html

currently I am using a javascript in my wordpress site. Which will create a div first then will render some content from external source in it. But, it is not working because of && , escaping issue. I need to bypass && . I also tried woth & but it is not working too. After deleting &&, div has been created but not working, as it is functional and I have to perform a AND operation. Is there any other way that I can perform logical AND operation without using && ?  Code format :-

```
if(k.className == "divbox" && k.getAttribute("data-push") != "1") { 
JSCode 
}
```

Comment: please put some code you have done so far

Comment: Isn't fixing the escaping issue something to try first? Otherwise, an if statement with one operand nested inside another if statement with the other operand could work depending on what you are trying to use an AND for.

Comment: Updated the post with code format.

Comment: Inside a HTML attribute such as `onclick="..."`, you should escape such characters using the `&amp;` form of escape sequences (this applies to several other characters too). However it is not at all clear where you are trying to enter this code so you may need to use a different escape sequence. Also it's worth noting that putting javascript in HTML attributes (`onwhatever=""`) is considered heavily dated, and you should provide your javascript as an entirely separate resource whenever possible (e.g. via the wordpress theme), where such issues will not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disclaimer:

**Please do not use this proposal in any production code!**
**This is for eduactional use only!**

You can replace the logical AND `&&` in a condition with a multiplication operator `*`, because a boolean value becomes either `0` (false) or `1` (true).

The right replacement for it in conditions renders the multiplication to the wanted result.

```
a  b a*b   result
-  -  -   --------
0  0  0 -> false
0  1  0 -> false
1  0  0 -> false
1  1  1 -> true
```

Suggestion:

```
if ((k.className == "divbox") * (k.getAttribute("data-push") != "1")) {
```

Comment: Technically a solution, but better to fix the actual problem (escaping characters or finding a suitable place to put the code) than obfuscate the meaning like this. This is how spaghetti code begins.

Comment: Please, don't ever write any code like this. It is so obfuscated, it will be extremely difficult to read and debug and other programmers will want to inflict bodily harm on you. If, for some reason, you ever DO write any code like this, comment the hell out of it.

Answer (score 0):

A && B is equivalent to !(!A || !B).

For your example that would be:

```
if(!(k.className != "divbox" || k.getAttribute("data-push") == "1")) { 
JSCode 
}
```

Still not very readable though.